# My inputcommand keybinding to main window does not work when child window is focussed(same wpf window)?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

I am facing one problem with input command key binding.
Here i explain my situation...
I have binded the input command key binding like below,

```
<Window x:Class="DefaultBehavior_KeyBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Add" Width="100" Height="35" Grid.Row="0" Name="EmptyButton" Click="EmptyButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

It works fine. Then i opened the new wpf child window in button click event like below,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.TestCommand = ........some command is attached here...
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void EmptyTabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window childwindow = new Window() { Title = "ChildWindow", Width = 200, Height = 300 };
        childwindow.Show();
    }
}
```

After opening the child window, the key binding to main window not working when child window is focused. If i switch the focus to main window means, it fine.

I know, both the main window and child window are independent to each other.

But my question is, how can i make it as work my child window is focussed when i binded the keybinding to main window only. i don't want to set this binding to each child window because in my case i am using lot of child windows.

Any one please provide your suggestion to me?

Comment: Can you please set  Focusable="False" for your childwindow.

Answer (score 0):

The key bindings will only work if the Form is focused.
You could redirect every Command in your new Window to the Main Window

Change your Constructor to of the new Window to accept a Main Window and save this window:

```
MainWindow mainWindow;
public Window(MainWindow w)
{
   mainWindow = w;
}
```

Whenever a Keybinding executes just do something like this:

```
mainWindow.TabPress();
```

And show the Window with

```
Window childwindow = new Window(this) { Title = "ChildWindow", Width = 200, Height = 300 };
childwindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the Input Bindings in Window style (that should defined in App.xaml), so that it will apply to all Window objects.

Answer (score 0):

This code is NOT TESTED! (but it should work anyways :D)

You could add the `InputBindings` from the `MainWindow` to the childwindows `InputBindingCollection` as follows:

```
    private void EmptyTabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window childwindow = new Window() { Title = "ChildWindow", Width = 200, Height = 300 };

        childWindow.InputBindings.AddRange(this.InputBindings);

        childwindow.Show();
    }
```

By doing so, the childwindow should react to your input and execute the commands from the `MainWindow`.